# How could I know the button is showing in RemoteViews?

Tags: android, show, visible

I have to Test my broadcast class witch has a remoteview in .
And I want to check the button in the remoteview weather is showing or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the view like this way. Hope help.

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); 
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate( R.layout.widget, null); 
View v = view .findViewById(R.id.text); 

assertFalse(v.isShown());
```

---